# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key violation

Tags: mysql

I am getting following error while trying to import sql dump through putty.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign k`.`#sql-79bd_378d`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3F27962AD89DB423` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`)
```

I have found similar questions on stackoverflow and got to know why i am getting this error. But my question is how i can find the culprit row which is causing this error in schools table?

Comment: Does the table you're trying to import data into have any foreign keys specified?

Comment: @EvanOJack -  I am importing whole database not just one table. It has foreign key defined like this: ALTER TABLE `school_tags`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_3F27962AD89DB423` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `schools` (`id`)

Comment: Maybe I didn't read your question correctly at first, it sounds like you know that the problem is you're importing a row that has a `school_id` that doesn't exist in the `schools` table. I'm not sure if this is the best way, so I won't put it as an answer, but have you tried creating a new table without the foreign key and import the data into it? Then you can query the rows in the new table to see which `school_id` doesn't exist in the `schools` table.

Comment: @EvanOJack - i deleted the row which doesnt exist still get this error. May be it is because of auto increment?

Comment: Did you try @LorenzoR's answer? Can you query `describe school_tags;` to show us how the `school_id` column is set up in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporary disable foreign key constraints.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

... import SQL...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```